# What can I do to set color palette in seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Instead of default option of `cmap`, I want to use my own specific colors for the heatmap like: `sns.heatmap(df, cmap = ...)`

For example, I want to use #A43E28 as the color for the min value and #144DB0 for the max value. However, in tutorial website, I only find some default option for `cmap` like `cmap="PiYG"`

Anyone knows how to set the color palette for heatmap?